# LevelHelper collision not working

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, levelhelper

This problem has stumped me for two nights now, I cannot simply have two `LHSprites collide` with each other using `level helper collision`. I have checked the [docs](http://www.gamedevhelper.com/documentation/documentation.html#collision) multiple times to check if I was missing something, but i cannot see it.

In the console of xCode, it logs:

```
 LevelHelper WARNING: Please call useLevelHelperCollisionHandling after addObjectsToWorld
2013-04-24 20:33:04.537 Monkeys2D[1322:c07]
 LevelHelper WARNING: Please call registerPostCollisionCallbackBetweenTagA after useLevelHelperCollisionHandling
```

But as you can see in my code below, I am correctly doing what it is warning me that I am not.

```
-(id) init
{
if( (self=[super init])) {

    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

    loader = [[LevelHelperLoader alloc]initWithContentOfFile:@"Level1"];

    [loader addObjectsToWorld:world cocos2dLayer:self];

    [loader useLevelHelperCollisionHandling];

    [loader registerPostCollisionCallbackBetweenTagA:MONKEY andTagB:SINGLEBANANA idListener:self selListener:@selector(collision)];

}
return self;
}
```

My problem is that the collision will NOT register, it acts as if nothing is even happening when the `MONKEY` and the `SINGLEBANANA` collide.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can u post your `collision` method?

Comment: i remember getting the same thing randomly.. try resetting your simulator and clean your project..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i needed to add an `update` method and implement some other box2d stuff, visit the level helper docs & forum to see.